# Stacking Issue in Bootstrap 3 Desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the Boostrap 3 grid system. I have a navigation header that i'm trying to customize in the regular desktop screen resolution. The columns work fine until I size the screen down to about 1200px wide. Then the left two links - a button and a regular link start stacking. I don't know how to resolve this. When I change the column sizes the middle column menu links start stacking which I don't want either. I feel like I am missing something really basic here. And I am a newbie in advance so my apologies for lack of knowledge in certain areas.

The live link is here:

http://www.splashdesignstudios.com/template/template3.html

Comment: Please edit your question to include a working example of the problem code.  Links to off-site "live" examples are not as useful because they might change or go offline at a later date.

Comment: What exactly DO you want? No stacking at all?

Comment: In your source, you're using `<ul class="navlist">` which I'm not familiar with in Bootstrap's source. Did you read the docs at http://getbootstrap.com/components/?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/watersnow/2r4v4Lwp/ - Code

Comment: No stacking above 1024px

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the navbar bootstrap and the collapse plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img alt="Brand" src="img/mocklogo.png" style="height: 100%;">
        </a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link7</a></li>
        </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span>Login</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom"><span class="fa fa-search"> &nbsp;</span>Sign Up</button>
        </form>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

You can change the appearance just by changing the bootstrap-css. You can find some themes at the [bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com/).

Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/m5cfwopa/) to see how it's working. In this example, I'm using the `Paper` theme.

Hope it's useful!

Comment: Thanks Academia. I customized the css and formatted this, in Chrome is working ok, but in Firefox the right buttons still collapse below the other menu items around 1200px resolution? Any thoughts on how this can be fixed. http://splashdesignstudios.com/template/template4.html

Comment: @watersnow: When one customize the navbar, he should be really careful. you have changed key styles like position, that why, it's no longer working in no browser. You should can styles like color, dimensions, etc but not position.

Answer (score -1):

Specifying fixed width classes to three columns gives less width to last column once your screen size reduces. I would divide the header into two columns (both with display: table-cell and vertical-align: middle) with first one containing the logo and menu and second one containing the buttons. However, to make it act properly under 1200px, you will need to use media queries and adjust the styles for every element accordingle.